# SSE gives no speedup for C++ number crunching

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, x87

I have a heavy number-crunching program that does image processing. It is mostly convolutions. It is written in C++ and compiled with Mingw GCC 4.8.1. I run it on a laptop with a Intel Core i7 4900MQ (with SSE up to SSE4.2 and AVX2).

When I tell GCC to use SSE optimisations (with  -march=native -mfpmath=sse -msse2 ), I see no speedup compared to using the default x87 FPU.

When I use doubles instead of floats, there is no slowdown.

My understanding is that SSE should give me a 2x speedup when using floats instead of double. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Did you check the assembly generated to see whether the code was really vectorized? Did you try GCC's debug option (`-ftree-vectorizer-verbose`) to see whether the code was really vectorized?

Comment: The floating point operations are probably not what's limiting your performance in that case. From your question it seems like you are compiling without other optimizations?

Comment: Are you sure gcc was even using x87 FP before?  At least for x86-64, the default has always been `fpmath=sse`, which should only give a small speedup over x87 for scalar code.  If the compiler can vectorize anything, and it's not memory-bound, then you could expect speedups with `-march=native`

Comment: And if you're not compiling for x86-64, you really should.  The x86 calling convention has args on the stack, not in registers, so calling a non-inlined function with FP args and an FP return value means loading args from the stack into xmm registers, then storing the result to a temp buffer, then loading the result into the x87 FPU where the ABI says the return value has to go.  (`-mfpmath=sse` doesn't change the ABI, only what happens inside functions.  This is all that matters if your hot loops have any function calls inlined, though).

Comment: Mingw GCC is 32 bits, so it targets an x86 system, where SSE is disabled by default. I will look into Mingw-64 see if I get improvements from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that SSE should give me a 2x speedup when using floats instead of double. Am I mistaken?

Yes, you are.

Compiler is as good as your code - remember that. If you didn't design your algorithm with vectorization in mind, compiler is powerless. It is not that easy: "turn the switch on and enjoy 100% performance boost".

First of all, compile your code with `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=N` to see, what really was vectorized by the compiler.

`N` is the verbosity level, make that `5` to see all available output (more info [can be found here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2005-01/msg01247.html)).

Also, you may want to read [about GCC's vectorizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#using).

And keep in mind, that for performance-critical sections of code, using SSE/AVX intrinsics ([brilliantly documented here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)) directly may be the best option.

Comment: I used -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=N and it showed me nothing was vectorized unless I use -O3, and even then, most of the code could not be vectorized because it contains control statements. So I was indeed wrong and your answer helped me understand why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code, no description on test procedures, but it generally can be explained this way:

1. It's not all about cpu bound, it's also bounded by memory speed.
   Image processing usually have large working set and exceed the amount of cache of your non-xeon cpu. Eventually the cpu encounter starvation means the overall throughput can be bounded by memory speed.
2. You may be using an algorithm that is not friendly for vectorization.
   Not every algorithm benefits from being vectorized. There are many conditions have to meet - flow dependency, memory layout, etc.

Comment: He said there was no slowdown when changing from `float` to `double`, so that rules out a memory bottleneck (unless locality is horrible, and most loads aren't getting prefetched, so mem latency is the issue, not bandwidth.)  But probably the issue is #2: autovectorizing failure.  Scalar SSE math is barely faster than scalar x87 math.  Long dependency chains could easily be the bottleneck, leaving enough execution resources to churn through the extra stores / loads / x87 stack ops needed when using x87 instead of flat xmm registers.

Comment: So the cause was #2, but Peter Cordes is also right that memory bandwith (and cache size) are not the bottleneck here (if they were using doubles would slow down the program). So performance may be limited by memory latency (because of poor cache filling) or just CPU non-vectorized performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outside chance that this is related to my problem with system libraries distributed with the Mingw GCC port using x87 80 bit FP internally.

Based on a couple of random test pieces not intended to be vectoriser friendly I reckon the improvement for going from pure x87 code to SSE2 or higher at double precision should be around 25% on arithmetic heavy code that isn't memory bandwidth limited. And AOTBE another 40+% faster for float vs double.

```
 double BM_Pi(double x)
 {
  int n = 20;
  double f = 1;
  while (--n)
    f = (2 * n - 1) + n * n / f; // phi has f = 1 + 1 /(f + 1) here
  return 4/f;
 }
```

Forcing x87 code generation by pretending to be an i586 and then allowing all optimisations -O3 these are the results for different compilers I have to hand:

| Compiler | Phi | Pi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intel AVX2 | 30 | 77 |
| MS AVX2 | 63 | 102 |
| MS x87 | 84 | 115 |
| GCC AVX2 | 61 | 95 |
| GCC x87 | 83 | 116 |

What I see on some memory intensive (not vector friendly) code is that SSE2 FP is sometimes fastest by about 20% than AVX and 10% faster than AVX2. It is obviously very code dependent. The Intel compiler has probably found a way to vectorise the Phi test (exact factor of two faster is suspicious).

Comment: Both your benchmarks include FP division latency in a loop-carried dependency chain.  That gets significantly worse with more precision.  Also, this can't vectorize because it's one dependency chain.  Depending on how you enabled AVX2 (e.g. `-march=x86-64-v3` or `-march=haswell`), you might also have enabled FMA.

Comment: You forgot to mention what CPU and what exact compiler version.  Tiny loops like this can be sensitive to microarchitectural differences.  (And potholes on some CPUs, like Skylake-family: [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646))

Comment: @PeterCordes They were intended to be awkward. Real code is typically better than this. It was chosen to have almost one of each operation in - I expect strength reduction means it is actually  FP ++ - * / per loop. CPU i5-12600 compilers Intel2023, MSC2022 and GCC 13.1.0 (MinGW port).  I would normally avoid having divides in such close proximity it was intended to test worst case behaviour.