# How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?

Tags: gcc, x86, intel, gnu-assembler, compiler-flags

If I have a chip that is subject to the [Intel jcc erratum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016077/32-byte-aligned-routine-does-not-fit-the-uops-cache/61016915#61016915), how I can enable the mitigation in gcc (which adjusts branch locations to avoid the problematic alignment), and which gcc versions support it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By compiler:

- GCC: `-Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`
- clang (10+): `-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries` compiler option directly, not `-Wa`.
- MSVC: [`/QIntel-jcc-erratum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qintel-jcc-erratum?view=msvc-170) See [Intel JCC Erratum - what is the effect of prefixes used for mitigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216761/intel-jcc-erratum-what-is-the-effect-of-prefixes-used-for-mitigation)
- ICC: TODO, look for docs.

---

The GNU toolchain does mitigation in the assembler, with `as -mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`, which enables ([GAS manual: x86 options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dOptions.html)):

- `-malign-branch-boundary=32` (care about 32-byte boundaries).  Except the manual says this option takes an exponent, not a direct power of 2, so probably it's actually `...boundary=5`.
- `-malign-branch=jcc+fused+jmp` (the default which does *not* include any of `+call+ret+indirect`)
- `-malign-branch-prefix-size=5` (up to 5 segment prefixes per insn).

**So the relevant GCC invocation is** `gcc -Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`
Unfortunately, GCC `-mtune=skylake` doesn't enable this.

GAS's strategy seems to be to pad as early as possible after the last alignment directive (e.g. `.p2align`) or after the last jcc/jmp that can end *before* a 32B boundary.  I guess that might end up with padding in outer loops, before or after inner loops, maybe helping them fit in fewer uop cache lines?  (Skylake also has its LSD loop buffer disabled, so a tiny loop split across two uop cache lines can run at best 2 cycles per iteration, instead of 1.)

It can lead to quite a large amount of padding with long macro-fused jumps, such as with `-fstack-protector-strong` which in recent GCC uses `sub  rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28` / `jnz`  (earlier GCC used to use `xor`, which can't fuse even on Intel).  That's 11 bytes total of sub + jnz, so could require 11 bytes of CS prefixes in the worst case to shift it to the start of a new 32B block.  Example showing 8 CS prefixes in the insns before it: https://godbolt.org/z/n1dYGMdro

---

**GCC doesn't know instruction sizes, it only prints text**. That's why it needs GAS to support stuff like `.p2align 4,,10` to align by 16 if that will take fewer than 10 bytes of padding, to implement the alignment heuristics it wants to use. (Often followed by `.p2align 3` to unconditionally align by 8.)

`as` has other fun options that aren't on by default, like `-Os` to optimize hand-written asm like `mov $1, %rax` => `mov $1, %eax` / `xor %rax,%rax` => `%eax` / `test $1, %eax` => `al` and even EVEX => VEX for stuff like vmovdqa64 => vmovdqa.

Also stuff like `-msse2avx` to always use VEX prefixes even when the mnemonic isn't `v...`, and `-momit-lock-prefix=yes` which could be used to build std::atomic code for a uniprocessor system.

And `-mfence-as-lock-add=yes` to assemble `mfence` into `lock addl $0x0, (%rsp)`. But insanely it also does that for `sfence` and even `lfence`, so it's unusable in code that uses `lfence` as an execution barrier, which is the primary use-case for `lfence`.  e.g. for retpolines or timing like `lfence;rdtsc`.

`as` also has CPU feature-level checking with `-march=znver3` for example, or `.arch` directives.  And `-mtune=CPU`, although IDK what that does.  Perhaps set NOP strategy?

Comment: clang's support still seems pretty limited as of clang-16, it doesn't seem to consider fusion and it uses (variable length) `nop` instructions rather than redundant prefixes which seems mostly strictly worse at least for small number of prefixes.