# Multiplying a struct (storing a float) by a float is coming out to be faster than simply multiplying a float by a float?

Tags: c++, struct, floating-point, operator-overloading, compiler-optimization

I needed a way of initializing a scalar value given either a single float, or three floating point values (corresponding to RGB).  So I just threw together a very simple struct:

```
struct Mono {
    float value;

    Mono(){
        this->value = 0;
    }

    Mono(float value) {
        this->value = value;
    };

    Mono(float red, float green, float blue){
        this->value = (red+green+blue)/3;
    };
};

// Multiplication operator overloads:
Mono operator*( Mono const& lhs, Mono const& rhs){
    return Mono(lhs.value*rhs.value);
};
Mono operator*( float const& lhs, Mono const& rhs){
    return Mono(lhs*rhs.value);
};
Mono operator*( Mono const& lhs, float const& rhs){
    return Mono(lhs.value*rhs);
};
```

This worked as expected, but then I wanted to benchmark to see if this wrapper is going to impact performance at all so I wrote the following benchmark test where I simply multiplied a float by the struct 100,000,000 times, and multipled a float by a float 100,000,000 times:

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    size_t N = 100000000;

    std::vector<float> inputs(N);
    
    std::vector<Mono> outputs_c(N);
    std::vector<float> outputs_f(N);

    Mono color(3.24);
    float color_f = 3.24;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++){
        inputs[i] = i;
    };

    auto start_c = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++){
        outputs_c[i] = color*inputs[i];
    }
    auto stop_c = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_c = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop_c - start_c);
    std::cout << "Mono*float duration: " << duration_c.count() << "\n";

    auto start_f = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++){
        outputs_f[i] = color_f*inputs[i];
    }
    auto stop_f = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_f = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop_f - start_f);
    std::cout << "float*float duration: " << duration_f.count() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it without any optimizations: `g++ test.cpp`, it prints the following times (in microseconds) very reliably:

```
Mono*float duration:  841122
float*float duration: 656197
```

So the `Mono`*`float` is clearly slower in that case.  But then if I turn on optimizations (`g++ test.cpp -O3`), it prints the following times (in microseconds) very reliably:

```
Mono*float duration:  75494
float*float duration: 86176
```

I'm assuming that something is getting optimized weirdly here and it is NOT actually faster to wrap a float in a struct like this...  but I'm struggling to see what is going wrong with my test.

Comment: Numerous possibilities - compiler optimisers can reorder operations, omit operations as long as computed/output results (distinct from timing) are consistent with what the standard says.  `high_resolution_clock` is not guaranteed to be good quality, and it is not unknown for some (poor) implementations to be non-monotonic i.e.  time can seem to go backwards.   You might try doing things in different order (e.g. do the `float*float` calcs first) and see what changes.  Only way to be sure is to examine code emitted by your compiler.  Also, consider using `steady_clock` instead.

Comment: @Peter yeah I tried reordering it, and changing up the operations, but the behavior persisted.  I unfortunately lack the know-how to dig into what the compiler is actually doing, so for now I'm going to have to try it and benchmark in my actual full use-case to evaluate any change of performance there.

Answer (score 1):

On my system (i7-6700k with GCC 12.2.1), whichever loop I do second runs slower, and the asm for the two loops is identical.

Perhaps because cache is still partly primed from the `inputs[i] = i;` init loop when the first loop runs.  (See https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/ re: Intel's adaptive replacement policy for L3 which might explain some but not all of the entries surviving that big init loop.  `100000000` floats is 400 MB per array, and my CPU has 8 MiB of L3 cache.)

So as expected from the low computational intensity (one vector math instruction per 16 bytes loaded + stored), **it's just a cache / memory bandwidth benchmark** since you used one huge array instead of repeated passes over a smaller array.  Nothing to do with whether you have a bare `float` or a `struct {float; }`

---

As expected, both loops compile to the same asm - https://godbolt.org/z/7eTh4ojYf - doing a `movups` load, `mulps` to multiply 4 floats, and a `movups` unaligned store.   For some reason, GCC reloads the vector constant of `3.24` instead of hoisting it out of the loop, so it's doing 2 loads and 1 store per multiply.  Cache misses on the big arrays should give plenty of time for out-of-order exec to do those extra loads from the same .rodata address that hit in L1d cache every time.

I tried *[How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646)* but it didn't make a difference; still about the same performance delta with `-Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`, so as expected it's not a front-end bottleneck; IPC is plenty low.  Maybe some quirk of cache.

---

On my system (Linux 6.1.8 on i7-6700k at 3.9GHz, compiled with GCC 12.2.1 -O3 without `-march=native` or `-ffast-math`), your whole program spends nearly half its time in the kernel's page fault handler. (`perf stat` vs. `perf stat --all-user` cycle counts). So that's not great; if you're not trying to benchmark memory allocation and TLB misses.

But that's total time; you do touch the input and output arrays before the loop (`std::vector<float> outputs_c(N);` allocates and zeros space for N elements, same for your custom struct with a constructor.)  There shouldn't be page faults inside your timed regions, only potentially TLB misses.  And of course lots of cache misses.

---

BTW, clang correctly optimizes away all the loops, because none of the results are ever used.  `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize(outputs_c[argc])` might help with that.  Or some manual use of asm with dummy memory inputs / outputs to force the compiler to materialize arrays in memory and forget their contents.

See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation)