# Does effective throughput of an instruction depend on the data it operates on?

Tags: cpu-architecture, physics, energy

According to comments the answer is: **yes**

Alternative (equivalent) question:
*Does heat generation (energy) of an instruction depend on data?*

Clock speeds of modern chips are often limited by the amount of heat generated by instructions and thus the ability of the environment to cool down the chip. In some cases doing integer arithmetic, one has in principle the ability to choose whether to work with binary representations containing a larger number of 1s than 0s.

**Do instructions which operate on data with a larger number of 1-bits consume more energy and thus generate more heat?**
*What actually matters are changes in the bit state, see comments.*

Consider this example of OR-ing two 16 bit registers:

```
2 bits being set - low energy use?

   1000000000000000
OR 0000000000000001
-------------------
   1000000000000001


16 bits being set - high energy use?

   1010101010101010
OR 0101010101010101
-------------------
   1111111111111111
```

Intuitively I would expect that there is a difference as typical transistors have high switching energy loss. (See *[Why does switching cause power dissipation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614018/why-does-switching-cause-power-dissipation)* on ee.SE)

For floating point operations one can probably not make use such an effect as the binary representation of the mantissa is more or less random.

Comment: With an operation like logical or, you still have to perform the or on each pair of bits. I think you're question would be more interesting if it pertained to arithmetic operations, particularly multiplication and division.

Comment: @SimonGoater: CMOS logic generates heat when logic gates change their output from low to high or vice versa. (*[Why does switching cause power dissipation?](//electronics.stackexchange.com/q/614018)*)  Other than division, ALUs don't have "early out" that can skip some of the work in special cases, but I'd expect a 64-bit `0 * 0` or FP `0.0 * 0.0` or `1.0 * 1.0` (all-zero mantissa and unchanging exponent) might use less energy than with random data.  Perhaps even doing any FMA with the exact same inputs repeatedly would have the logic gates in fully-pipelined multipliers not changing state.

Comment: @SimonGoater: That might be a measurable level above the background of all the control logic on modern x86 if doing nothing but SIMD multiplies.  The effect might be there for other operations, but not to a measurable level, especially for something extremely cheap like OR, even SIMD 512-bit `vpord`.

Comment: It's not the number of `1` bits that matter, it's bits *changing* (inside ALUs).  In CMOS logic, no current has to flow to maintain a logical `1` state or a `0` state, which is why CPUs use CMOS logic rather than older higher-power technology like TTL or ECL based on bipolar transistors that have much higher static power, vs. just leakage in CMOS.  Writing the result to the physical register-file entry will change bits depend on the previous contents of the *physical* register, not the architectural register.

Comment: Throughput?  Only possibly indirectly (via CPU frequency changes) for workloads that are too power-intensive to sustain max turbo.  Perhaps for workloads like Prime95 that spend all their time doing 256-bit SIMD FMAs, the difference in power could perhaps be enough for some laptop or server chips to run at a slightly higher frequency.  Maybe even for some desktops.  For most other workloads, control logic and out-of-order exec machinery (like front-end, RAT, scheduler, ROB) would dwarf the power difference from data differences.  Especially bitwise booleans.

Comment: Your original question about power / energy was more interesting. With battery-powered mobile computing being important, and CPU energy consumption being a well-known thing to care about in general, it's a clearer and more direct question that way.  The edit to ask about throughput makes it worse, IMO, especially without even mentioning the connection between power and clock frequency.

Comment: An editor claims that the original question is not relevant to stackoverflow. I tried to rebuke that claim. I only made additions and no deletions to the question, so the original question is still there. I do not possess what seems to be esoteric knowledge that is required for formulating a question in such a way that it pleases the editors. This is my final edit of the question, I regard the issue as settled.

Comment: BTW, I just tested this on my i7-6700k Skylake at 3.9GHz.  (Linux energy-performance-preference = balance_performance on kernel 6.5.9-arch2-1).  https://godbolt.org/z/z5j7oW9Gv is the full nasm source with `perf` results in comments; the loop is just `times 11 vmulpd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm1` / `dec rbp/jnz .loop`, aligned to avoid the [JCC erratum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256646/how-can-i-mitigate-the-impact-of-the-intel-jcc-erratum-on-gcc).  Squaring vectors of either `0.0` or `3.1415926535`.

Comment: With all-zero, `perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/ sh -c './testloop & ./testloop & ./testloop & ./testloop & wait;'`, I got a total of 814.21 Joules +- 6% for 4 all-zero run, vs. 897.10 +- 0.5% for 4 runs with non-zero data.  Each run kept all four physical cores busy with 2/clock `vmulpd`.  I wasn't sure the energy difference was going to be that measurable.  It was less visible with total package power (`intel_gpu_top`) and only running one single-threaded process.