# Why is Rust port of function 2x slower than C++?

Tags: c++, rust, optimization, benchmarking, edit-distance

I have a function to compute String edit distance in C++:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

size_t sed_diff(const std::string & a, const std::string & b) {

    std::vector<size_t> cp(b.length() + 1);
    std::vector<size_t> cc(b.length() + 1);

    // Edit distance on postorder traversal.
    for (int j = 0; j <= b.length(); ++j) {
        cp[j] = j;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); ++i) {
        cc[0] = i;
        for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); ++j) {
            unsigned int c1 = a[i - 1];
            unsigned int c2 = b[j - 1];
            cc[j] = std::min({
                                     cp[j - 1] + ((c1 == c2) ? 0 : 1),
                                     cc[j - 1] + 1,
                                     cp[j] + 1
                             });
        }
        std::swap(cp, cc);
    }
    return cp[b.length()];
}

int main() {
    // call
    sed_diff(std::string("banana"), std::string("mango"));
    return 0;
}
```

I attempted to rewrite the same in Rust code:

```rust
fn sed(s1: &[u8], s2: &[u8]) -> u32 {
    let mut cp = vec![0u32; s2.len() + 1];
    let mut cc = vec![0u32; s2.len() + 1];

    for i in 0..=s2.len() {
        cp[i] = i as u32;
    }

    for i in 1..=s1.len() {
        cc[0] = i as u32;
        for j in 1..=s2.len() {
            let c1 = s1[i - 1];
            let c2 = s2[j - 1];

            cc[j] = std::cmp::min(
                std::cmp::min(cp[j - 1] + if c1 == c2 { 0 } else { 1 }, cc[j - 1] + 1),
                cp[j] + 1,
            )
        }
        std::mem::swap(&mut cp, &mut cc);
    }
    cp[s2.len()]
}

fn main() {
    sed(
        String::from("banana").as_bytes(),
        String::from("mango").as_bytes(),
    );
}
```

When benchmarking the code on the same dataset, the C++ code averages around 15 seconds, while the Rust compiled code averages around 30 seconds total runtime.

Both tests are run in a nested for loops, using 20 000 input strings and 50 test strings.

But I can't understand, why the Rust version is so much slower?

**EDIT:**

CPU is AMD's Ryzen 5 4500U.
I compiled C++ code using **g++** (v13.2.1) + CMake in Release mode, so AFAIK only `-O3` flag was used.
Rustc version is v1.75.0.

As for tested inputs as I mentioned in the comments, the strings are generated DNA sequences with lenghts of 95 up to 105 chars long.
E.g.:

```
ATGATGGTCAGGTAGTGGAGAGGCTTACATATGGCCACATATCGGTCAAAAGCCATGGCTATGAGCAGCACCATC
TCAGTTCCCCCAACTGCATGGATAA
```

I used 20 000 input strings with 50 query strings with nested for loops (query string in outer loop).

Comment: what are the compiler arguments for both C++ and rust ?

Comment: Rust: standard cargo release profile, C++: CMake standard Release profile, no other special flags

Comment: Rust bounds-check array accesses. If the optimiser does not manage to elide the bounds check they will be present at every indexed access (read or write). C++ does not bounds-check accesses. Your code is full of indexing.

Comment: Because of handling of edge cases, Rust's inclusive ranges often lead to poor code generation, half-open ranges (or no ranges at all as per previous) are generally much preferred, and faster.

Comment: Can you include some simplified benchmarking code, in both C++ and Rust? It might be interesting to play around with the code.

Comment: Another difference (that might actually be in favor in Rust, at least in large strings) is that `size_t` is usually 64 bits on 64-bit platforms, not 32 bits.

Comment: Does anything change when you compile with `export RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native"` and `[profile.release] panic = "abort"`?

Comment: Expanding on Masklinn's answer, if you replaced your `operator[]` calls with `at()` calls in the vector you probably will see much closer performance results. There is a substantial difference between the two as one can seg fault and the other can't. In C++ we tend to use unsafe index operations and in rust you're forced to be explicit. I've never used it, but if you called [get_unchecked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get_unchecked) then theoretically will get much more similar performance to your c++ code

Comment: @LittleBoxOfSunshine I believe (didn't benchmark though) that the difference should be attributed more to the usage of inclusive ranges and less to the bound checks.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Why? Isn't the code with inclusive range just equivalent to the difference between a for loop with the `<` operator compared to the `<=` in C++ (that is generally no difference for native integers)? (assuming bound-checking is disabled)

Comment: @JérômeRichard No it is not, because `<=` has a subtle bug: if it overflows, the loop becomes infinite. Rust's inclusive ranges handle this by adding a boolean, but this complicates the code and slows it down _much_.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ok. Surprising! Why they do not check if the value is close to the limit before the loop and generate two codes (one fast for most cases and one for a value close to the limit)? AFAIK, this is something compiler like Clang partially does for aliasing already for example.

Comment: Which C++ compiler is used by the way? Note that the standard Rust compiler use LLVM so it would be fair to compare this to Clang in C++ and not GCC. GCC and Clang can generate binaries having pretty different performance (especially when one generate a SIMD friendly code and not the other).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't know how much effort has been put into improving the current codegen. Also, due to the nature of Rust iterators, if we do such check we'll have to do it every iteration, so if LLVM will not manage to unify the checks it will be even costlier.

Comment: I see, if the compiler doesn't have an alternative way to optimize that it would make a big difference yeah. It'd be interesting to see assembly outputs for just the iteration and vec lookup portions to see what all differences are there with checked and unchecked access in both languages

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and explanation so far. The compiler for C++ is actually **GCC**. I will try to improve the rust code with suggestions above as well using Clang for C++ compilation as soon as I can. I will post the results as soon as I can. For anyone wondering, the benchmarking dataset i used are generated DNA strings of lengths between 95 and 105 chars long.

Comment: Edit your question with details of which compiler versions and options (like `g++ -O2` or `g++ -O3 -march=native`), and your details about your data sets. Also what CPU you tested on.

Comment: If any of this did auto-vectorize, using 64-bit `size_t` in the C++ should have made the C++ version 2x slower than Rust using `u32`.  Or worse since `-march=x86-64-v2` and higher have a single instruction for packed-min of `u32` but not `u64` until AVX-512.

Comment: Oh right, the inner loop has a dependency on the previous iteration via `cc[j-1] + 1`, so compilers can only vectorize the `cp[j] = j;` init loop. https://godbolt.org/z/Ga348sxxf shows GCC and Clang -O3 making basically the same inner loop with branchless `setne` for the `==` and 2x `cmp`/`cmov` for the `min`.  If you're on a Skylake-family CPU, perhaps try [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646) or the Rust equivalent, maybe Rustc got unlucky?  Or maybe this is just bounds checking throughput if that doesn't optimize away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rustc fails to keep `cc[j] = min(...)` in a register to become next iteration's `cc[j - 1]`, instead it actually stores + reloads, creating a longer latency bottleneck.  This is on top of the branchless 2x `cmp/cmov` and `add` (+1) that's probably about 5 cycles to get `min` of 3 inputs.  Store-forwarding latency is usually about 5 cycles on typical modern x86, so that explains the 2x speed difference.

https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/ / https://agner.org/optimize/.  On some CPUs like Zen 2 and Zen 4, and Ice Lake, zero-latency store forwarding is possible, but that usually requires the same addressing mode, not just the same final address.  (https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41)

Or maybe there's a throughput bottleneck as well for the GCC version.  GCC does `min(cp[j] + 1, cp[j - 1] + (c1 != c2))` first because that's independent of last iteration's `min` result that's now in `cc[j - 1]`, so the actual critical path latency is only `add`/`cmp`/`cmov`, 3 cycles on Broadwell and later, or AMD.

Without compiler versions/options and CPU model, and details on your microbenchmark to see if the function inlined and compiled differently, the precise explanation for the exact speed difference will have to wait, but the bottom line is a missed optimization by the Rust compiler.

You could probably help it out by using a local variable instead of re-reading an array element with the bounds-checking that entails in Rust.

---

The inner loop has a dependency on the previous iteration via `cc[j-1] + 1`, so compilers can only vectorize the `cp[j] = j;` init loop.

It's this loop-carried dependency that appears to be a throughput bottleneck in the Rust `-C opt-level=3` code-gen, because Rustc / LLVM made asm that reloads it from memory instead of keeping the result of last iteration's `min` in a register.

Perhaps it has a harder time optimizing than in C++ because of the bounds checks (there are some extra `cmp/jcc` conditional branches in the inner loop, but I don't think that would account for a factor of 2 in throughput.)  But LittleBoxOfSunshine's answer tested with `get_unchecked` and found negligible speedups, so probably just LLVM misses this.

GCC code-gen for the inner loop looks like this (after changing the type to `unsigned` to match your use of `u32` in Rust), **[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAEx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApJIBCZ86SX1kBPAMqN0AYVS0AriwYgALADspC4AMngMmABy3gBGmMQgkkEADqgKhI4M7l4%2B/ilpGQJhEdEscQlJNph2DgJCBEzEBNnevgDMABxVNZn1jQTFUbHxiUEKDU0tuZ02EwPhQ2UjSQCUNqiexMjsHGZt4cheWADUJm2u48ThwGfYJhoAgnsHR5in5wBumPYkt/dPkn2DEOnhOZ1cYmAJEICBYf0e/3SAC9MAB9AjHJToVH4KhUCBoBjjTEEdAgECXa6nSQANmOTFIx0JxPGZIpBCuRmpdJiK1OAUsCMeAHphcdxSS2V8fsRwci0QRbkzkhAYgA6ehGAgICB8qzHLgrM6Ch6iiWS8nSoiy87y9FK5DIVUaxjAbW66nmA1Gtom812jFiWioZCozXvAAix2dmrdOr1FgNnuOAQTdIAtB1jeKzcQNgx0MdPMljkR6ccWJ5aA5kvRjqgqMcOsd%2BMRjpg8XhkHhGBihABJACyUfChH%2B5rNngYrYIU6YBGqAE9Swh58d0KhMAoGGAOBilJgWKXUMcENUSwBxVyuekfVB4QtTvO0WhUhSiAxtw6YQzF47hFc3lHDFg1QZJxwlVlLW%2Ba1wSndJgAidAHRVIMQzDRgfT9SDSWgmU4KJPBEMwZC2mwJknTQ0NNSw/4IJzMVcEIdc8HGQxtnrBhjlScYSCwNsOSYL5iAUMQ1XolsSGjcIMW0SNjg0bM5PBM4oyojCGGzKwrG0PUBWOM02kkdMYmY0CSzQKcFzbVt207bte2OAdh3/Bgx0ec1zWQcCAFZzG0EwfKjVTjgC30JJMAIIwks0A2OcymXzayFEktsoQwCsfwUTZMEZFg0gIWhlzLdJNQ4gB3Ro3KMBRxI8iVbIgOK8HkrhsxalS2jUl0tXjLSLCsPA9OwzyKMC8xFKC%2BS8GNCTzXgoikNcjFkC4eSmHGlr0wNQLot9BiV1Y/8UvM9Nwg%2BRo8EMAhGQQe9iUINVxXcFhkjoeIUvKuhaHXE9tSOwxF0qxc5oaqSmrwFF0VC1qlPeVwQvVWN3Swz0dOG0HRtFBbiMLGSmTWkKNr8radqC2b6tG%2BbCNx5amUkeSYnGuTtra8nwspqnxUdZndvkqCQBYcIIEikaufFiWqe85njlZvn9SgVbIxC5BJD1NoADEFOOEBvVITHJcNqXTD8lmyeCxMuH1zmjdt0bpdN%2BXLYNu3RsiiNaJtiV3YNgWFEqlVvMZR1PYec0fc54hMFnYguId8wkddFHdopp4orox58ZYJhhYxzmzQ/WgJKxHE8DxJrcPZTlgBFyRJBiQxG7MNXGT9jlrlryRs6MVBm5WUPzSjmOuMUjm04jDg1loTgfN4XwOC0UhUE4BGBsTBQNi2N49h4UgCE0Se1gAaxANo2jVM/L6v6%2BaX0Tg/Dng%2Bl84XgFBADQ94PtY4FgJA0Fe96ZAKAElQAA%2BgCRgBcCMnwOgyVKAxCfqZZgxBFycF3kgxoi4ADyMRtAwTQbwf%2BbBBBYIYEVJ%2BWAYieGABCF8b9uC8CwN3YA4gF6MLwFHeweAvj0MXpgVQ3xPALgIeQQQ1Qn6vhiMQTB7gsBP3biwAhawqAGGAAoAAaj2cqWDkiMBEfwQQIgxDsC4H4GQghFAqHUGw0gugrYGCMCgbSFh9B4BiG/SAawwK1CJJwdMWC2iy2zlsBAqlVAdBpOmGkfh0wfECemAA6kGXgqBhJXCwB43U3QYKZGcAWKYvg/BtGCAWQYpRygSD8FbHihQsgeFaP4YpNSfFlOGAkUxVtbA5LqHMAp/gP5dK4T0/orSljtKqbMfofS/ADLmKMipHS1gb02NsCQU8Z6PxscvDgxxwmROiccYAjoDTnwZhAJi1pqRtENLwfebD%2B6kBPmfC%2B19Xln1vtPDgD9SDz0Xts1%2B79P73NID/RAKBQFvXAeQSg/9IUjEOIYSBAQNBWxoNWD68DEHhEwSIjBKCcF4PsCIohvZSHkJsZQ6htDaD0N3kwxFrDF74E4Q4HhT9%2BGCOEQw0RC5PmL0kdIlBsidiLwUUovgqiNFaJ0Xo7lBjhAfhMWY%2BVli1BP10NIBxxhnHWEkZkrxyQfH0P8fE4JyBQldT2VEmJcTZZJJfCktJD4tzwCWdUbpvgIAuD6VwD%2BoQFjlJGKYgAnKQZpmQfVhoKC0gNbTKmhsGT4vokx6m5F9dkoZDBk3zBKHGkNkyU05F8J0uZsaxnxqWZvVZho74cFnj8p%2B2zdkROtUyLVBoAhqg0GqNa5z8CXJ3isW5X9j6n3Pm8t5tbvm/JSS/GwgK7laAeZ8yQmy/lzsXYfUgwl0hOD8EAA)**.  I know you actually benchmarked a version that used 64-bit `size_t` elements for the vectors, assuming you compiled for x86-64, but that's not significant.  For your small strings, these easily fit in L1d cache.

```
# GCC13 -O3 -march=x86-64-v3 -Wall   but this loop didn't use any new instructions
.L15:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*4]        # EAX = cp[j]
        xor     esi, esi
        cmp     BYTE PTR [r9-1+rdx], dil
        setne   sil                               # ESI = (c1 != c2)
        add     esi, DWORD PTR [rbx-4+rdx*4]      # ESI += cp[j-1]
        add     eax, 1
        cmp     esi, eax
        cmovbe  eax, esi                          # eax = (esi<eax) ? ESI : EAX
        add     ecx, 1
        cmp     eax, ecx
        cmovbe  ecx, eax
        mov     rax, rdx
        mov     DWORD PTR [r14+rdx*4], ecx     # store the result
        add     rdx, 1
        cmp     r15, rax
        jne     .L15
```

Note that there are only two DWORD loads plus the BYTE load (of the char from the string).  And none of the loads are using `r14` in the addressing mode like the store is.  So we can see there are no loads from `cc[]`, just a store, so `cc[j - 1] + 1` must be computed from last iteration's store.

Another possible optimization would have been to keep `cp[j]` around for use as `cp[j-1]` next iteration, but looking at the addressing modes is enough to figure out that it didn't do that.

Clang is weird, with what looks like two versions of the loop, one with setcc/cmovcc and another with branches (starting at `.LBB0_38:` I think).

But Rustc (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAEx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DEArgoKkl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywYgAHNMcAZPAZMADl3ACNMYgkANlIAB1QFQjsGFzcPb2kEpNsBAKDQlgiorlirTBsUoQImYgI0908AdgBmS0xrXIZq2oJ8kPDImMsauoaM1pHe/sLimIBKS1QTYmR2DjiTMIBqKgZtpXQIBS4QbYBSSWjzgFYAIRMvW4ARUgPJM8vr%2B8eX%2Be2ALTnFrYbYmFqSC5NO7nDQAQW2iO29AI2xYJlRyDiFxaz22ADcKmAwLc7hpwZJgXd3gA6egMCD/S7UrgvKmwhFIlFojHbZDIHF4wnIYmk8kQqm0%2BmMi6SFlslow%2BEcpG7EjbPAa/YaGk04HPBSSOmMGXnaEq1VIrGkvAvQUa7ZMBRgiWKi2Is3PDnutXEB2BbZcXX6k7GhlM83wy1W5Biu36h1Ol2Ut1R6O%2B7baLWB4O4w1h02RznprmYTFce0nG2AwMKpXFkvIst8yEJw2krMA2s3L2puE%2Bkv8jvx3EHAjoEAoFhxScsQIQAeNxHmCdTmcgOcM633TvdvHMjVUPkV/UJ5Ct6HbDRQvEdJRQlk3t5Dnc11k92UsxaLpfbu7aeM5UDUgf0teZQM9UCV1nTAWEnBQAHcmDiBcrnRTE4jeL50L5ZBwL7VVILTRE/3zaVwJ7b0mi9ZV4U2MIOT2NEmHnCN61VQ4F2Iy1qmIQJQBAKhiFQFhUMkMJDEky5JHmGknQAfTCABPAhMAURkQO41VeP4ychJEsSWEMYBUGk2SFOU1T1O/bj8PrT0OEWWhOBuXhPA4LRSFQTgACUzFRBRllWTBZRaHhSAITRHMWABrEAWhaGkEuSlLUtiZyOAAFjcqKvM4XgFBADQIqixY4FgJA0GnOhInISgqriGqomILgmhuYqaFoVTiEKiAwlysJAlqJTOHCwbmGIJSAHkwm0CpIu4XgqrYQQpoYWgRo83gsDCExgCcMRaEKxbSCwIyjHELbTrwYh5rwQljs8zBVAqDF1nCwJVIyzzaDwMJiGGlwsFygg%2BLgxbFioAxgAUAA1PBMAQqa4kYUbeH4QQRDEdguEymRBEUFR1Cu3QuH0YyQFMcx9D%2BwrIEWVA4i6Y6AScbZGYIAF6EJWh9RaXhUEJYg%2BKwOmNPKSp7AgRxxk8LgblIfxAgGIohkkLxYmyZIBFliQFa1roZkGKJ1bKDo7oEHoxlcRo9Alrorb6ZXZjVjWpmt9I5fdp2CmNkBTcWQKVjWCQnJcnKru8jhtipggBSDNqaWvCBcEIdVLjC%2BZeAWrR5li%2BLEtSovkvSzhstIdzPKjgqipKraypgRAQGWAhNgsCgIAaprglYdZY/jmlE6e/AiBFvQMeEURxFx/H5CUNRctJ0gEIBmcIf0cOK9yqOpoxNv2aPfucyH7YIBcar6D9DOuCzuvc/zhKkuLouN6yiOq/yyxa5z6LX8kd%2BBafx/nnUgQskj2EykAA)**) has one inner loop:

```
.LBB0_20:
        cmp     rdi, r15
        adc     r10, 0                 # r10 += (rdi<r15) unsigned
        lea     r11, [rdi - 1]
        cmp     r11, r15
        jae     .LBB0_21               # bounds check?
        cmp     rdi, rbx
        jae     .LBB0_27               # these are based on 64-bit unsigned compares, so they're not u32 or char data
        xor     r11d, r11d
        cmp     r9b, byte ptr [rbp + rdi - 1]
        setne   r11b                           # r11 = (c1 != c2)
        add     r11d, dword ptr [r13 + 4*rdi - 4]
        mov     r12d, dword ptr [r14 + 4*rdi - 4]   # load from [r13 + scaled-idx]
        inc     r12d
        cmp     r11d, r12d
        cmovb   r12d, r11d
        mov     r11d, dword ptr [r13 + 4*rdi]
        inc     r11d
        cmp     r12d, r11d
        cmovb   r11d, r12d
        mov     dword ptr [r14 + 4*rdi], r11d      # store to [r14 + scaled-idx]
        cmp     rdi, r15
        jae     .LBB0_31
        mov     rdi, r10
        cmp     r10, r15
        jbe     .LBB0_20
```

So the main work is still done branchlessly like GCC.

But unlike GCC, it's actually storing/reloading `cc[j - 1]`, so store-forwarding latency becomes part of the loop-carried dependency chain critical path which is the bottleneck.

---

#### Optimized Rust version

Seeing these problems in the asm, we can change the source to make it easier for the compiler to avoid them.  Use a local `mut lastccj` variable to hold `cc[j]` across iterations, and use `lastccj` only in the outer `min`, not as an input to the inner one, to keep the critical path latency down to `inc` / `cmp`/cmov`, with the first` cmp/cmov` being independent.

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAEx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DEArgoKkl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtEywYgAzAHZSjgBk8BkwAOXcAI0xiEElpAAdUBUI7Bhc3D28/ROTbASCQ8JYomLjLTGs8hiECJmICdPdPX3LK1Jq6ggKwyOjY6XNOxsyWwfruopL%2BgEpLVBNiZHYOeJMIgGoqBnWldAgFLhB1gFJJADZjgFYAIRMADiuAEVIdySPTi5v7p%2Bn1gFpjl5sOsTF5JCcfNdjhoAILreHregEdYsEzI5DxE5eR7rABumGQYDAV2uGlBkkB11eADp6AwIL9TlSuE9KdC4QikSi0etkMgsTj8YTiTcyWDKTS6QyTpJmayvFDYeyEZsSOs8OrthpqdTAY8FJJaYxpcdIcqVQiMSS8E8Ber1kwFCDxQrzfDTY92W7VcR7cF1lwdXqDkb6YyzbCLZbkCSNLa9fbHc6Ka7I1HEZh0Vw7Qdrf8A/LFRyo1zUciDOY%2Bdo7XzY4XvSr%2BL7q/7A7rsQbQyaI8X0/CuchwQmDSTq38C5dPamYQB6ABUDfTM5niIEwGivOIKVEtHW8SYBAQLzMwWAiMdBCrmvWh8wmzwxHMKP9tDwAGs77f1iQ8MBgmJFxLC8r2HAh0BAFAWHiCCWGCCBAL7HYwIg5AoJguCrRuMcJxxJl1SoXlsz1BNBwhKkNAhHEKiUMiA0ol4K0vZBqzwrhZgQvtMOubR41lANSA4hFpjZWE5xnQT%2B2A5ic2QyDoJAWD6Qki1zHAuT0PpLjsJZScZSpCBkGzIkSMkX4k3JF4tN45l2LTRCLUYkC%2BJZOzEOE6d7PhWssPjbFz0rZiRN7FUPQQ1SYMwFgIIUAB3Jh4ng84y15eIXg%2BZK%2BXcosQp8T1XK4zspWEycvVyr1YVWCJ2S2FEmDg8NsoRXZ4NclUai3IwIKoYhUBYRLJAiQwhtOUzqUdAB9CIAE8CEwBQGQE1qEXa08up6vqRpYQxgFQEbpjGhRJpmuaFu9LLSseDhZloThLl4TwOC0UhUE4AAlMxkQUeZFjvU4vB4UgCE0K7ZjfbwvGpLwoehmGYbOfROAAFnu4Hns4XgFBADRAeB2Y4FgJA0CguhonISgifiEmYmILgfEubGaFoWbH0oCJUYif9iCmzgAY55guYAeQibQCSB7heCJthBAFhhaG5x7eCwCITGAJwxFoTHxdILAtqMcQFe1h9RbwfFNaezBVAJNFlgB4JZpug3XwiYg6imlwsFRggtyi8XZioAxgAUAA1PBMBigX4kYHneH4QQRDEdguERmRBEUFR1AN3QuH0baQFMcx9DwCJMcgWZUHiKpNb%2BJxvwrv56HxWg9S8XhUHxYgtywEuFqsY37AgRxhk8bPAmCHpij6bOchSAQh70aeqgmXoYmz3ubHaWp6jn1eKj76pN66MfJknywD%2B30/OiXieV9mL6FiWCRrtulGDZejh1nzy8A2pOnqQoiBcCEDVH9NivAxZaGmKDcGkNYawKhvDB2yNSAPSem/DGWMcYKzxjARAIB5gEFWBYCgBleqU3oMQUIrBlif35IGX%2B5t8BEE7noWOwgdyJ2TqwtOahUZZ1IDFF20FfYIw4HdZBqM34CzRIQ78BEaHf3oesCALhibkJlP9aYYDcZQKhjAuBsMRFIJQa3dGlgMHgJBiIyQL9UGmIsZA0g7dkj2ERkAA%3D%3D)

```
// Improved version of the loop.
    for i in 1..=s1.len() {
        cc[0] = i as u32;
        let c1 = s1[i - 1];
        let mut lastccj = cc[0];
        for j in 1..=s2.len() {
            let c2 = s2[j - 1];
            lastccj = std::cmp::min(
                std::cmp::min(cp[j - 1] + (c1 != c2) as u32, cp[j] + 1),
                lastccj + 1   // only needed after the first min result is ready
            );
            cc[j] = lastccj;
        }
        std::mem::swap(&mut cp, &mut cc);
    }
```

This is obviously somewhat less readable and harder to follow, so it would be nice if compilers did a better job.  There might also be something to gain from `cp[j-1]` vs. `cp[j]`, using a temporary variable for that, but that's just a throughput issue so we'd have to look if that saves instructions.  Modern x86 can do 2 or 3 loads per clock cycle so the back-end execution units aren't the limit, just getting all the instructions through the front-end and issued into the back-end.  Especially with the bounds-check overhead, this loop is far from tiny.

Perhaps some SIMD to prepare a buffer of `std::cmp::min(cp[j - 1] + (c1 != c2) as u32, cp[j] + 1)` results would help.  That could maybe even auto-vectorize.  Could be very good with AVX-512 merge-masking, but could still go 8 elements at a time with AVX2 with a few instructions.

But the final loop is going to have a 3 cycle loop-carried dependency and the bounds-check overhead, so there's a limit to how much speedup we can get.

https://uica.uops.info/ predicts that the inner loop from this optimized version bottlenecks at one iteration per 5.36 cycles on Skylake, one per 4.7 cycles on Ice Lake / Rocket Lake.  (Or 4.2 cycles with perfect scheduling).  Those are both worse than the 3-cycle latency bottleneck.  So the bounds-check branching becomes part of the throughput bottleneck after fixing the latency bottleneck.  CPUs with 6-wide pipelines like Alder Lake P-cores or [Zen 3 or 4](https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/) could run it even faster, in theory one per 3.5 cycles.

Would it work to manually vectorize with SIMD prefix-scan techniques for the chain of `min` operations?  Maybe not, because I'm not sure it's separable into a prefix-min of `cc[j]+1`; the min with elements from `cp[j]` can affect an older `cc[j]` in ways that we can't correct for later.  So the mix of `+1` and `min` makes it not associative, I think.

Comment: Re-ran the test Peter's hint optimized version included. 2K trials of 20K pairs of random words (to avoid continuous branch predictor hits; from disk for repeatability) on AMD Ryzen 9 3900X.

sed Elapsed 4.956ms
sed_unchecked Elapsed 4.841ms
sed_asm_aware Elapsed 3.998ms
sed_asm_aware_unchecked Elapsed 3.775ms

And for people that would like to compare the various outputs, minibench [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3TTEv7s9K).

Checked vs unchecked continues to be minor, Peter's tweak gets to about ~1.6x OP's reported C++ speed ratio.

Comment: @LittleBoxOfSunshine: Thanks for testing. As expected, `unchecked` is more useful once the latency bottleneck is removed.  I was hoping it would give a larger improvement on the [OP's use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932428/why-is-rust-port-of-function-2x-slower-than-c/77934671?noredirect=1#comment137394353_77932428) of DNA sequences with 95 to 105 letters.  Maybe your random "words" were much shorter than that, so less of the total time is spent in the inner loop?

Comment: Also, 3 to 5 milliseconds is really short, but long enough for interrupts to potentially happen.  But it's still long enough to time reliably without timing overhead being killer.  As long as you're running lots of these short tests and discarding outliers (e.g. take the median or mode), that's fine.  With just one test, that would be short enough that you'd worry about the CPU getting from idle to boost clock frequency.

Comment: Good to clarify and be explicit about it yeah, the words are much shorter on average. Since OP has the data set, and access to the various versions of the function, I figured rather than hoping to recreate their data set faithfully it'd be interesting to see what the impact of the compiler's suboptimal choice was more generally. It'd be nice if OP can share the final result as their use case appears to be more sensitive to the distinction