# What does the event `stall_slot_backend` represent?

Tags: linux, arm, perf, performancecounter

I am trying to diagnose low cycles-per-instruction in a small program. Using `perf stat -e cycles,stalled-cycles-backend ./myprogram`, I see that around 90% backend cycles are idle.

```
Performance counter stats for './myprogram':

        5207951548      cycles:u                                                    
        4704755172      stalled-cycles-backend:u  #   90.34% backend cycles idle    

       3.485708464 seconds time elapsed
```

My understanding is that the hardware counter assigned to `stalled-cycles-backend` is incremented whenever the fetched instructions are not dispatched due to resource constraints like result of memory loads, unavailability of floating point units etc, and the pipeline fills up with bubbles. I would like to drill further down into why exactly the backend is getting stalled.

On looking through some other events using `perf list`, I came across the following, among others.

```
--snip--
stall_slot            [Kernel PMU event]
stall_slot_backend    [Kernel PMU event]
stall_slot_frontend   [Kernel PMU event]
--snip--
```

Using `perf stat -e cycles,stall_slot_backend .build/release/Run`, I see the following result.

```
 Performance counter stats for './myprogram':

        5207682200      cycles:u                                                    
       28628535485      stall_slot_backend:u
```

So, this event supposedly happened more times than the number of clock cycles. I do not quite understand what this even means. From my processor's [technical reference manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101779/0003/Debug-descriptions/Performance-Monitoring-Unit/PMU-events) (ARM Cortex A78AE), this is the description for `stall_slot_backend`.

> No operation sent for execution on a slot due to the backend

Which is not very illuminating. I could not find the definition of slot elsewhere in the manual. So, I have the following questions.

1. What exactly does a slot mean in this context?
2. Why is the count for this event more than the number of clock cycles? Is it possible for a counter to be incremented more than once per cycle? Or could these results be erroneous or misleading?
3. What is the difference between the hardware events/event groups `stall_slot_backend` and `stalled-cycles-backend`?

Comment: One possible meaning for an unused "back-end slot" is when a pipe doesn't start an instruction that cycle.  A typical modern ARM has 3 or more integer pipes, and at least a couple SIMD/FP pipes, and some memory pipes.  (Intel would describe those as "execution ports").  That's compatible with the numbers here.  Some CPUs have more back-end pipes than the front-end width so it's inevitable that the average counts would be at least 1 per cycle. Yes, it's 100% normal for a counter to be able to increment multiple times in the same cycle, e.g. events like `instructions`.

Comment: Oh, execution ports would make sense. And man I should've thought about the `instructions` counter... So, if in a given cycle the counter is incremented by say +3, then would that mean that there are 3 fetched instructions waiting for slots to become available?

Comment: No, the opposite.  It would mean there are 3 execution ports that didn't have an instruction issue to them.  (Either because there were none in the scheduling queue for that port, or because none of them had their operands ready.)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. So,  to distinguish between the case where none were scheduled and where operands were not ready, is that the difference between `stall_slot_frontend` and `stall_slot_backend`?

Comment: To add some more context, this is very closely related to this unanswered question that I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759602/why-does-this-code-speed-up-when-the-main-function-is-moved-inside-the-loop 

The version that's executing much fewer instructions is paradoxically much slower, and the difference seems to be between their `stalled-cycles-backend` to `cycles` ratios.

Comment: Lower IPC (instructions per cycle) would tend to correlate with a higher average `stalled-cycles-backend` per `cycles`; very low IPC often happens due to full stalls like cache misses or branch mispredicts that result in no work being ready to start this cycle.  i.e. schedulers empty, or full with work whose inputs aren't ready, assuming this is an out-of-order CPU.  You haven't mentioned what CPU you're using.

Comment: My CPU is the same as the linked reference manual, ARM Cortex A78AE, which is OOO. I looked at the cache miss rates and branch misprediction rates, but they seemed quite low. I'll double check in a while. Empty schedulers sounds like a front-end problem due to e.g. instr cache misses and decoder being bottlenecked? In this case the frontend stalls are less than 0.1%.

Comment: Yup, empty schedulers would be a front-end problem.  So probably that's not what's happening here.  Low IPC without any of cache misses or branch misses can be due to a latency bottleneck, e.g. linked list load-use latency or summing an FP array without multiple accumulators (so there's only one dependency chain, thus one add per 3 cycles or whatever the latency of FP add is.)  Or store/reload store-forwarding latency, like in [Why is Rust port of function 2x slower than C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77934671)